# Ciel and Receipt from Codechef - Getting right answer but Codechef says wrong, Any mistake im not seeing?

Tags: java

Im trying to solve this question im getting right answer but codechef says wrong every time can someone help me in this problem
https://www.codechef.com/problems/CIELRCPT
My code is as follows:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public final class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int testCases = sc.nextInt();
        int input;
        int divisor[] = { 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128, 256, 512, 1024, 2048 };
        while (testCases-- > 0) {
            input = sc.nextInt();
            int count = 0;
            int temp = 0;
            for (int i = 11; i >= 0; i--) {

                if (input > 2048) {
                    input = (int) (input - divisor[i]);
                    count++;

                }
                if (input >= divisor[i] && temp + divisor[i] <= input) {

                    temp += divisor[i];
                    count++;

                }

            }

            System.out.println(count);

        }
        sc.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: try with 8192. The result should be 4 (4x2048)

Comment: Thanks got the problem solved .. never tried above 4096 ..problem was on code :)